# Algorithm analysis:  Am I analyzing these algorithms correctly? How to approach problems like these

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

1)

```
  x = 25;
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
    {
        if (myArray[i] == x)
            System.out.println("found!");
    }
```

I think this one is O(n).

2)

```
for (int r = 0; r < 10000; r++)
    for (int c = 0; c < 10000; c++)
        if (c % r == 0)
            System.out.println("blah!");
```

I think this one is O(1), because for any input n, it will run 10000 * 10000 times.  Not sure if this is right.

3)

```
a = 0
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        a++;
}
```

I think this one is O(i * k).  I don't really know how to approach problems like this where the inner loop is affected by variables being incremented in the outer loop.  Some key insights here would be much appreciated.  The outer loop runs k times, and the inner loop runs 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + k times.  So that sum should be (k/2) * (k+1), which would be order of k^2.  So would it actually be O(k^3)? That seems too large.  Again, don't know how to approach this.

4)

```
int key = 0;    //key may be any value
int first = 0;
int last = intArray.length-1;;
int mid = 0;
boolean found = false;

while( (!found) && (first <= last) )
{
    mid = (first + last) / 2;

    if(key == intArray[mid]) 
        found = true;
    if(key < intArray[mid])
        last = mid - 1;
    if(key > intArray[mid]) 
        first = mid + 1;
}
```

This one, I think is O(log n).  But, I came to this conclusion because I believe it is a binary search and I know from reading that the runtime is O(log n).  I think it's because you divide the input size by 2 for each iteration of the loop.  But, I don't know if this is the correct reasoning or how to approach similar algorithms that I haven't seen and be able to deduce that they run in logarithmic time in a more verifiable or formal way.

5)

```
int currentMinIndex = 0;

for (int front = 0; front < intArray.length; front++)
{
    currentMinIndex = front;

    for (int i = front; i < intArray.length; i++)
    {
        if (intArray[i] < intArray[currentMinIndex])
        {
            currentMinIndex = i;
        }
    }

    int tmp = intArray[front];
    intArray[front] = intArray[currentMinIndex];
    intArray[currentMinIndex] = tmp;
}
```

I am confused about this one.  The outer loop runs n times.  And the inner for loop runs 
n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... (n - k) + 1 times?  So is that O(n^3)  ??

Comment: 3) is O(k^2) because you will do k*(k+1)/2 ops, which is O(k^2). 5) is the same: the inner loop runs n, then n-1, then n-2 ... then 1 time, so overall n*(n+1)/2 times, so O(n^2).

Comment: 5) is bubble sort (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), which is O(n^2).

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Doesn't the inner loop run n*(n+1)/2 times?  And doesn't the outer loop run n times.  So isn't that [ n * ( n*(n+1)/2) ]

Comment: @ordinary: check my answer, what matters is the number of times you perform the comparison, so it's only the total number of times that the inner loop runs, ie n*(n+1)/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More or less, yes.

1 is correct - it seems you are searching for a specific element in what I assume is an un-sorted collection. If so, the worst case is that the element is at the very end of the list, hence O(n).

2 is correct, though a bit strange. It is O(1) assuming `r` and `c` are constants and the bounds are not variables. If they are constant, then yes O(1) because there is nothing to input.

3 I believe that is considered O(n^2) still. There would be some constant factor like k * n^2, drop the constant and you got O(n^2).

4 looks a lot like a binary search algorithm for a sorted collection. O(logn) is correct. It is log because at each iteration you are essentially halving the # of possible choices in which the element you are looking for could be in.

5 is looking like a bubble sort, O(n^2), for similar reasons to 3.

Comment: Can u please see the point 3, can that be O(n^2). have a doubt coz inner loop is going to iterate to 0.5 times of outer loop, so its not completly O(n^2).

Comment: @PunithRaj , For point 3 - If you are considering outer loop as O(n) and inner loop as O(n/2). Then we should consider it as O(n^2). According to Big O O(n/2) is O(n). Because n/2 increases linearly based on input 'n'. E.g. If n = 100 then n/2 = 50. If n= 10000 then n/2 = 5000 etc.

Answer (score 1):

O() doesn't mean anything in itself: you need to specify if you are counting the "worst-case" O, or the average-case O. For some sorting algorithm, they have a O(n log n) on average but a O(n^2) in worst case.

Basically you need to count the overall number of iterations of the most inner loop, and take the biggest component of the result without any constant (for example if you have k*(k+1)/2 = 1/2 k^2 + 1/2 k, the biggest component is 1/2 k^2 therefore you are O(k^2)).

For example, your item 4) is in O(log(n)) because, if you work on an array of size n, then you  will run one iteration on this array, and the next one will be on an array of size n/2, then n/4, ..., until this size reaches 1. So it is log(n) iterations.

Comment: No, there's theta and.. something else for best and average case. Big O is always worst case.

Comment: Agreed for the theta notation, though many people use O for average case; A quick sort is often said to be O(n log n)...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is mostly about the definition of O().

When someone say this algorithm is O(log(n)), you have to read:

*When the input parameter n becomes very big, the number of operations performed by the algorithm grows at most in log(n)*

Now, this means two things:

1. You have to have at least one input parameter n. There is no point in talking about O() without one (as in your case 2).
2. You need to define the operations that you are counting. These can be additions, comparison between two elements, number of allocated bytes, number of function calls, but you have to decide. Usually you take the operation that's most costly to you, or the one that will become costly if done too many times.

So keeping this in mind, back to your problems:

1. n is myArray.Length, and the number of operations you're counting is '=='. In that case the answer is exactly n, which is O(n)
2. you can't specify an n
3. the n can only be k, and the number of operations you count is ++. You have exactly k*(k+1)/2 which is O(n2) as you say
4. this time n is the length of your array again, and the operation you count is ==. In this case, the number of operations depends on the data, usually we talk about 'worst case scenario', meaning that of all the possible outcome, we look at the one that takes the most time. At best, the algorithm takes one comparison. For the worst case, let's take an example. If the array is [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]] and you are looking for 4, your intArray[mid] will become successively, 5, 3 and then 4, and so you would have done the comparison 3 times. In fact, for an array which size is 2^k + 1, the maximum number of comparison is k (you can check). So n = 2^k + 1 => k = ln(n-1)/ln(2). You can extend this result to the case when n is not = 2^k + 1, and you will get complexity = O(ln(n))

In any case, I think you are confused because you don't exactly know what O(n) means. I hope this is a start.